# Filling large and small jugs of water from 50L

Tags: contest-math

This is Question 21 from the AMC Junior Division 2016:

Angelo has a $50$ litre barrel of water and two sizes of jug to fill, large and small. Each jug, when full, holds a certain amount of litres.

Angelo fills three large jugs, but does not have enough to fill a fourth one. With the remaining water he fills three small jugs, but does not have enough left to fill a fourth. What is the capacity of the small jug in litres?

---

$L$ = Large jug
$S$ = Small jug
$R$= Remainder left after third small jug was filled

So
$50$ L = $3L$ + $3S$ + $R$

What do I do now? I have a feeling that this question will involve simultaneous equations, but I'm not sure. How do I go about this?

P.S. Please explain in the math skill of the participants which are taking this competition e.g. Year 7&8 (although Year 9 is fine too.) I've also got no idea about which tag to use, other than contest-question.

Comment: Don't use the same symbol for different things! You used $L$ for litres and for a large jug volume...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question! However, I would suggest using "whole amount of litres" instead of "certain amount of litres". Also for the remainder: "not enough whole amount of litres left to fill the fourth".

You started well:
$$3L+3S+R=50 (*)$$
If $R$ is dropped, LHS becomes smaller:
$$3L+3S<50 \Rightarrow L+S<\frac{50}{3}\approx 16.67  \ \ \ (1)$$
The water after the three large jugs was not enough for the fourth:
$$3S+R<L \ \ \ (2)$$
If in $(*)$, the value $3S+R$ is changed to the bigger $L$, LHS becomes bigger:
$$3L+L>50 \Rightarrow L>12.5 \ \ \ (3)$$
Also from $(1)$:
$$L\le 15 \ \ \ (4)$$
so that $S\ge 1$.

The water after the three small jugs was not enough for the fourth:
$$R<S \ \ \ (5)$$
If in $(2)$, the value $S$ is changed with smaller, LHS stays smaller:
$$3R+R<L \Rightarrow R<\frac{L}{4}\le \frac{15}{4}=3.75.$$
Thus, possible values of $R$ are $1, 2, 3$. However, from $(*)$ it is obvious $R$ can be only $2$ for $50-R$ to be divisible by $3$. Hence from $(*)$, $L+S=16$. Finally from $(2)$ and $(5)$, we can easily find $S=3$ and $L=13$.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try at explanation that would hopefully work for kids.

> Angelo fills three large jugs, but does not have enough to fill a
>   fourth one.

This sentence can be written as $3L < 50 < 4L$.

You could explain it by expanding on the sentence in a fashion: "Angelo fills three jugs, i.e. there is enough water to fill three large jugs, or 50 litres is more than volume of three large jugs.", or something similar. Also, $4L>50$ because if it would not be, Angelo would be able to fill another large jug.

*(Though, not quite, it is actually $3L\leq 50 < 4L$, but that first inequality is strict is implicit in the later text, and also, equality is impossible if integral values are assumed)*

> With the remaining water he fills three small jugs, but does not have
>   enough left to fill a fourth.

This gives us $3S \leq 50-3L <4S$.

The explanation is the same as before, with addendum that we now only have the remainder of water after filling large jugs, which is $50-3L$.

*(Note that now we cannot exclude equality case in our inequality.)*

---

Now, we have well defined problem in mathematical language. So, all that we have to do now is see how to deal with the system of inequalities

$$3L < 50 < 4L\\3S\leq 50-3L < 4S$$

and it depends on how familiar your students are with these kind of things.

Low level method of solving would be guessing that $13\leq L \leq 16$ since if $L \leq 12$, then $4L\leq 48$, and if $L\geq 17$, then $3L\geq 51$.

But, if your students are familiar with linear inequalities, just solve them to get $$\frac{50}4< L < \frac{50}3.$$

Now, it is basically casework: $L\in\{13,14,15,16\}$. Again, if your students are familiar with solving linear inequalities, first write

$$\frac{50-3L}{4}< S \leq \frac{50-3L}{3}$$ and then the casework becomes:

$1.$ $\frac{11}{4} < S \leq \frac{11}{3}$

$2.$ $\frac{8}{4} < S \leq \frac{8}{3}$

$3.$ $\frac{5}{4} < S \leq \frac{5}{3}$

$4.$ $\frac{2}{4} < S \leq \frac{2}{3}$

with only the first case giving us solution $L = 13$, $S = 3$.

If your students don't know how to solve linear inequalities, then the casework becomes

$1.$ $3S \leq 11 < 4S$

$2.$ $3S \leq 8 < 4S$

$3.$ $3S \leq 5 < 4S$

$4.$ $3S \leq 2 < 4S$

and still it is not too hard to guess the solution.

---

If your students are familiar with graphing linear functions, you can show them this graph:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We are given that $3L < 50 < 4L$ and $3S < 50 - 3L < 4S$. Since $S < L$, we get $50 < 3L + 4S < 7L$ and thus $L \geq 8$. Also, $3L < 50$ gives $L \leq 16$. We now try putting values for $L$ starting with $16, 15, \ldots$ and check we can get a value for $S$. Clearly, if $L = 16, 15, 14$ we can not find a value for $S$. When $L = 13$ and $S=3$, we get a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the values of $L$ and $S$ based on the information in the question:

You know that $3L < 50 < 4L$, which can be rewritten as $\frac{50}{4} < L < \frac{50}{3}$, and that $50 - 3L = R_{L}$, with $R_{L}$ being the remainder from filling the large jugs, from which the small jugs are filled.

Similarly, you then have $3S < R_{L} < 4S$. For each possible value of $L$, $R_{L}$ has a corresponding value, and you should be able to find out for each value of $R_{L}$ which values of $S$ are permitted, if any.